# Image enhancement using edge extraction

Tags: matlab

We can extract the edge of an image in MATLAB using the function `edge()`
My question is how can I recombine the edge with the original image to get an image with enhanced edges to increase the sharpness of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for already exists!

The image filter in question is called an 'unsharp mask'. It basically uses the edge data of an image to sharpen it. To elucidate, what it actually does in a manner of sorts is to use the difference of the image and a blurred version of it and then use that to sharpen the image. You can read more about it [here](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/tutorials/understanding-series/understanding-usm.shtml).

To use it, simply do something like the following:

```
>> my_image = imread('lena.jpg');
>> subplot(1,2,1);
>> imshow(my_image);
>> subplot(1,2,2);
>> imshow(imfilter(my_image,fspecial('unsharp')));
```

This would yeild:

[image]

As you can see, the second image is visibly sharper and this is done by "adding" the edge data to the original image through the use of the unsharp mask.

Comment: how do i use sobel mask to sharpen the image with threshold 0.1

Comment: @Abhilash: You can use `imshow(uint8(imfilter(im2bw(my_image,0.1),fspecial('sobel')))+my_image)`. With a threshold of just `0.1` though, the difference is very minute.

Comment: is there any other way of doing it....after i get the edges with the edge function ?

Comment: Maybe something like `C = my_image; C(edge(my_image)) = C(edge(my_image))*1.05; C(~edge(my_image)) = C(~edge(my_image))*0.95; imshow(C);`? Image enhancement is not an exact science; it really depends on the use case.

Answer (score 2):

Forget `edge()`. Just call [`imsharpen()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imsharpen.html)